# Fail to connect to master with Spark on Google Compute Engine

Tags: apache-spark, google-compute-engine

I am trying hadoop/spark cluster in Google Compute Engine through "Launch click-to-deploy software" feature .

I have created 1 master and 2 slave node and i can launch spark-shell on the cluster but when i want to launch spark-shell since my computer, i failed.

I launch :

```
./bin/spark-shell --master spark://IP or Hostname:7077
```

And i have this stackTrace :

```
15/04/09 10:58:06 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master
akka.tcp://sparkMaster@IP or Hostname:7077/user/Master...
15/04/09 10:58:06 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to
akka.tcp://sparkMaster@IP or Hostname:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@IP or Hostname:7077
15/04/09 10:58:06 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@IP or Hostname:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: IP or Hostname: unknown error
```

please let me know how to overcome this problem .

Comment: You need to set port 7077 to be externally accessible.

Answer (score 2):

See comment from Daniel Darabos. By default, all incoming connections are blocked except for SSH, RDP and ICMP. To be able to connect from the Internet to the hadoop master instance, you must open port 7077 for 'hadoop-master' tag in your project first:

```
gcloud compute --project PROJECT firewall-rules create allow-spark \
    --allow TCP:7077 \
    --target-tags hadoop-master
```

See [Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls), [Adding a firewall](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#addingafirewall) and [gcloud compute firewall-rules create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create) at GCE public documentation for further details and all the possibilities.

Comment: I just made a hadoop cluster and it allowed connections on all ports by default within the cluster.