# Opening open GCE firewall on elasticsearch instances for external connection

Tags: networking, elasticsearch, firewall, google-compute-engine

I've just created a elasticsearch cluster in GCE using "Click to Deploy", but I can only access it by using a tunnel. This is not a choice in my case, since there are other developers that I don't want to give gcloud access to. I would like to open port 9200 for elasticsearch so they could just connect to it by IP address and not with tunnel.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just double check you are running 1.4.3 or 1.4.4 as there was a considerable security vulnerability affecting earlier versions discovered this month.  if you created your cluster in April you should be all set.  You can check your version using this command:  curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open port 9200 in your GCE firewall for the elasticsearch instances. elasticsearch instances created by "Click to Deploy" have the "elasticsearch" tag defined, so, you can use the following command:

```
gcloud compute --project PROJECT firewall-rules create allow-elasticsearch \
    --allow TCP:9200 \
    --target-tags elasticsearch
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29540214/4161438) for additional information on GCE firewall configuration.

--edit to correct misspelling of elasticsearch