# How to allow external connection to elastic search on GCE instance

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, google-compute-engine

I'm setting elasticsearch cluster on GCE, eventualy it will be used from within the application which is on the same network, but for now while developing, i want to have access from my dev env. Also even on long term i would have to access kibana from external network so need to know how to allow that. For now i'm not taking care of any security considirations. 
The cluster (currently one node) on GCE instance, centos7.
It has external host enabled, the ephemeral option.

I can access 9200 from within the instance:

```
es-instance-1 ~]$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/?pretty'
```

But not via the external ip which when i test it shows 9200 closed:

```
es-instance-1 ~]$ nmap -v -A my-external-ip | grep 9200
9200/tcp closed wap-wsp
```

localhost as expected is good:

```
es-instance-1 ~]$ nmap -v -A localhost | grep 9200
Discovered open port 9200/tcp on 127.0.0.1
```

I see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29561826/opening-open-gce-firewall-on-elasticsearch-instances-for-external-connection) and following it i went to create a firewall rule. First added a tag 'elastic-cluster' to the instance and then a rule

```
$ gcloud compute instances describe es-instance-1
tags:
  items:
  - elastic-cluster

$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-elasticsearch --allow TCP:9200 --target-tags elastic-cluster
```

Here it's listed as created:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
NAME                    NETWORK  SRC_RANGES    RULES                         SRC_TAGS  TARGET_TAGS
allow-elasticsearch     default  0.0.0.0/0     tcp:9200                                elastic-cluster
```

so now there is a rule which supposed to allow 9200
but still not reachable

```
es-instance-1 ~]$ nmap -v -A my-external-ip | grep 9200
9200/tcp closed wap-wsp
```

What am i missing?

Thanks

Comment: In elasticsearch.yml there is a property "network.host:" if thats set to localhost than it can only be accessed via localhost. So you have to configure this. Alternativly just create a Tunnel for the port.

Comment: @DennisIch Have configured network.host - same result. Creating a vpn sounds like a good solution for what i'm trying to achieve. Thanks